# VueJs | "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" but it can

Tags: arrays, vue.js, methods, axios, typeerror

So I have a small problem but maybe some of you can help me.
I'm using Axios to fetch data with my Rest API and put the data (bookings) into an array. In the template I want the name of the of the desk instead of the Id, so I need to call a method which compare the id's and return the number.

There is the problem. It says this in the console: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".

But the weird thing is that it works. The message only pop-up one time (while the v-for generates around 15 items). I could just ignore the error message but I think something isn't working in the background. I think the problem is that the "getRightDesk"-method gets called before the Array "desks" get filled with data.

In the Template:

```html
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="data in api" :key="data.id" :item="data">
      <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ desks[getRightDesk(data)].description }}</td>
      <!-- Calling the method here -->
      <td>{{ format_date(data.start) }} Uhr</td>
      <td>{{ format_date(data.end) }} Uhr</td>
      <td class="last-td">
        <div class="wrapper-edit">
          <button
            class="button button-edit"
            @click="updateDate(data), editBooking(data)"
          >
            Bearbeiten
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-cancel">
          <button class="button button-cancel" @click="doDelete(data.id)">
            Löschen
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Important script parts:

```html
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'BookingElements',
  data() {
    return {
      api: [],
      url: 'https://localhost:7052/api/',
      start: '',
      end: '',
      bookingId: '',
      deskId: '',
      desks: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getBooking() {
      axios
        .get(this.url + 'booking', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.api = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    },

    getDesks() {
      axios
        .get(this.url + 'desk', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.desks = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    },

    getRightDesk(data) {
      let rightDesk = false
      let number = 0

      while (rightDesk == false) {
        if (this.desks[number].id == data.deskId) {
          // Here is the error message
          rightDesk = true
          return number
        } else {
          number++
        }
      }
    },

    format_date(value) {
      if (value) {
        return moment(String(value)).format('DD.MM.YYYY | HH:mm')
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.getBooking()
      this.getDesks()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

*Please ignore the bad code-writing-skills, I'm beginner*

Comment: Did you tried wrapping your `tr` tag inside of a `div` with a `v-if="api"`? The issue here is that your template is sync, while you do fetch some things from the API. Waiting for the array to be populated before displaying the data should fix it. Because otherwise, you're trying to access `id` on an empty array hence the error. Also, I recommend using `async mounted` + `await this.getBooking()` and `this.getDesks()` if you want to wait for the second call to wait for the first one to be done.

Comment: use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of the while loop

Comment: Also, prefer using `async/await` across all of your methods + use an alternative for moment (since it's now deprecated). +1 for the `while`, quite risky on a frontend to start with a possible infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @LawrenceCherone . Filter is way better than while and the error disappeared. I'll also use the tips from kissu to make it async because it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that improved OP's code + fixed the issues:

- wrapping `tr` inside of a `<div v-if="api">`
- using `async/await` across all functions
- using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) rather than a `while`